# split sequence into subsequences (possibly with a regex)

Tags: regex, r, sequence

I have a sequence which is a character sequence, mostly zeros and a very small chunk looks like this:

> 0001001099991091010000100005480010000

I would like to get all the pieces that are separated by one or more zeros.  So in the above case the correct values returned would be:

> 1,1,99991,91,1,1,548,1 (the commas are for illustration only)

I think a list of vectors would make the most sense as the returned data structure, but I can work with anything reasonable I think.  I have tens of thousands of strings and each individual string will be a thousand characters long at the most.  The only characters are 0 to 9 though.  This seems like it might be a regular expression problem, but my regex skills are not good enough to even be sure it is a good regex problem.  If a regex is the answer could someone help me out with this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the strings are like the one shown, then `strplit()` can do this for you:

```
vec <- "0001001099991091010000100005480010000"
strsplit(vec, "[0]+")
```

gives

```
> strsplit(vec, "[0]+")
[[1]]
[1] ""      "1"     "1"     "99991" "91"    "1"     "1"     "548"   "1"
```

Which is a list with one component (we passed it one string to split) but if you pass it `n` strings in a vector the returned object will have `n` components. Each component contains the substrings you wanted.

You'll need to convert to numeric if you want these as numbers but that is trivial. The other issue is that the run of `000` at the start of the example string. This leads to the empty string `""` that is the first element of the split string. We'll need to remove those too.

```
out <- strsplit(vec, "[0]+")
out <- lapply(out, function(x) as.numeric(x[nzchar(x)]))
```

This gives

```
> out
[[1]]
[1]     1     1 99991    91     1     1   548     1
```

Just a note on the regular expression used: `[0]+`. The brackets enclose the things we want to match, in this case only `0`s. The `+` means "one or more of". Which is why this works as `strplit()` will chop up the supplied strings wherever there are one or more `0`s.

Comment: `x[nzchar(x)]` (non-zero length characters) is the same as `x[which(nchar(x) > 0)]` just a bit simpler

Comment: @RichardScriven +1 - indeed it is; I don't use those things often enough to have them leap to mind it would appear.

Comment: Thanks Gavin!  Very elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

For many thousands of strings, you may want to use the very efficient `stringi` package.

```
x <- "0001001099991091010000100005480010000"

library(stringi)
stri_sub(x, stri_locate_all_regex(x, "[^0]+")[[1L]])
# [1] "1"     "1"     "99991" "91"    "1"     "1"     "548"   "1"
```

Basically this is locating all the non-zero character chunks in `x` and returning the substring.  To apply this method over many strings, you can use `Map()`

```
y <- rep(x, 3)
Map(stri_sub, y, stri_locate_all_regex(y, "[^0]+"))
# $`0001001099991091010000100005480010000`
# [1] "1"     "1"     "99991" "91"    "1"     "1"     "548"   "1"    
#
# $`0001001099991091010000100005480010000`
# [1] "1"     "1"     "99991" "91"    "1"     "1"     "548"   "1"    
#
# $`0001001099991091010000100005480010000`
# [1] "1"     "1"     "99991" "91"    "1"     "1"     "548"   "1"
```

There is also a `stri_split()` function in the package, but it will leave the empty characters at the beginning (like `strsplit()`) and end of they are zero.

Answer (score 0):

@gavin's answer is the more elegant one, but the brute force method also works:

```
input = '0001001099991091010000100005480010000'
output = character(0)
while(nchar(input)){
    if(grepl('^0',input)){
        # get rid of the unwanted bits
        input = gsub('^0+','',input)
        next
    }
    # keep the good bits
    output = c(output,gsub('0.*','',input))
    input = gsub('^[1-9]*','',input)
}
```